# getColumn(id).width is not the same as the width displayed by the browser

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I am using version 2.0a1 of Slickgrid, and I need to get some columns width in order to display some boxes on top of them (the box and the column need to have the same width).

Problem is, when I use `grid.getColumn(id).width`, it gives me a width that is slightly larger than the real width (real width as displayed by the browser -tried both chrome and FF7). Not sure where the difference is coming from.

If you know where the difference comes from, or if you know another way to get a specific's columns width, I would appreciate it.

Comment: *version 2.0a1* of what? Is this about JavaScript? Please provide more information, as it stands, no one can have a clue what you are talking about. If it is about JavaScript and you have a problems with layout/styling, you should also include your code and a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: Sorry as I came from Slickgrid's website I thought that this question would go to the Slickgrid category automatically. I just saw that there are no categories but only tags...my bad :)

Comment: There's a difference between `offsetWidth` and `style.width` and I have a suspicion that's where the difference comes in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The width reported by SlickGrid includes the padding and the border.